# Does XElement.Parse escape special characters

Tags: linq-to-xml, xelement

Assume i got code below, where

```
            xmlElement.AddAfterSelf(XElement.Parse(sbXml.ToString()));
```

- xmlElement : and XElement that contains a parent tag
- sbXml : StringBuilder with the xml string something like this `<Child name='Hi'></Child>` (unescaped of special charcters or xml entities, but a valid xml)

Does the `XElement.Parse` ensure to properly encode the special characters so that when i do `XDocument.Save` i don't hit with exception's ?

Comment: Don't use a StringBuilder to try to build XML in the beginning, use an API like LINQ to XML or XmlWriter.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That would be too cumbersone or am i doing it wrong ?  since i do `AppendFormat` and the xml goes inside to be replaced by parameters ex; `AppendFormat("<Child name='{0}'></Child>",childEntity.Name)`

Comment: Yes, you are doing it wrong, if `childEntity.Name` contains an ampersand `&` or a less-than sign `<` or a single quote `'` then your string builder approach would not produce well-formed XML. If you use `new XElement("child", new XAttribute("name", childEntity.Name))` and later save the XElement or the tree you add it to all is right.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Got it. Could you put above info in answer so that i can accept ? so `XElement.Parse` expects well formed xml to work without problems then

Comment: I have written an answer, based on our exchange in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XDocument.Load/Parse` as well as `XElement.Load/Parse` use an XML parser (which in the .NET framework is a concrete subclass of `XmlReader`) and of course that way it expects well-formed XML as the input. Using string concatenation to construct XML is not the right approach in the .NET framework as there are classes like `XmlWriter` and of course the tree based LINQ to XML or the DOM implementation which allow you to construct XML and ensure that any saved, serialized representation is well-formed XML (or you get an error indicating the problem when constructing and serializing the tree). So don't use string concatenation, instead build your XML with XmlWriter or with LINQ to XML, as for example with `new XElement("child", new XAttribute("name", childEntity.Name))`. That way, if `childEntity.Name` contains some characters (like `<` or `&`) that need to be escaped, the `Save` or `ToString` methods take care of that.